# Pinterest Pin It button and Facebook thumbnails don't work with uploaded images on WordPress blog. Why?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, pinterest

I have recently migrated from Blogger to WordPress, but am having issues with images.

Both Pinterest and Facebook are not recognising my new images that I am uploading to WordPress, however they do recognise the old images that have been imported directly from Blogger and still point to Blogger.

When I try to pin an image it allows me to select the image, but then when I click "pin" it says "Whoops! Sorry, We could not fetch the image".

With Facebook, trying to share the link, the posts with new uploaded images do not load any thumbnails, however the images from the old imported blogs do show thumbnails.

I have checked the pinning from a friend's blog that is based off the same theme and I can pin off their site. I have also checked whether the uploaded images are in iframes - they are not. I have verified my website with Pinterest.

Comment: Can you check the security settings applied to your uploaded images in WordPress. It sounds like they are secured in a way that Pinterest and Facebook cannot see them. When someone else (i.e., not logged in as you) looks at your blog, can they see the pictures that you uploaded via WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get around the issue for now by uploading the images to Photobucket and then linking into the post via the URL. So it seems that the issue is that they need to be hosted somewhere other than on my WordPress site.

If anybody else posts a better answer that doesn't require the workaround, then I'll accept theirs.